# Good Mac OS X app that allows server connection via FTP?

Tags: macos, ftp, editor

I'm looking for a web based FTP client, with a good PHP, javascript, html, code editor. possibly with unzip capability.
I've tried eXtplorer, but it's pretty buggy, especially the editor.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I thought about this and i decide that maybe it's better to have a desktop app that allows this kind of connection (read the comment below) instead of using a web app that is slower for sure.

So I change my question: Is there a mac os app that allows me to manage my server files via a protocol like web ftp, so that i'm not firewalled by public networks limitations?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Sometimes, I use internet connections that doesn't allow me to access my server via ftp, for example when i'm at the university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/)?  (I'm assuming you want PHP based on eXtplorer.)  I haven't used it, but a friend of mine said it worked pretty well once.

**Edit:** Based on your edit, are you just looking for a Mac FTP client?  There are certainly plenty of those around.  What is the specific requirement that's preventing you from using a normal one?  Is it that an FTP service can't be opened on that server for some reason?

If that's the case, what services can be made available on the server?  FTP on a different port?  SSH/SFTP, perhaps?

Comment: : ) sorry i upgraded my question!

Comment: no, ftp is working on my servers. the problem is that i'm often using the wifi connection of the university or some hotspot, and they don't allow ftp protocol transactions. I would like to have a very simple way to upload and edit files while on these connections.

Comment: @Bakaburg: A web FTP gateway, as prescribed by the original question, is probably going to be the most universal solution.  Other options are likely going to vary between networks.  Some may just block that port, and so you can run an FTP service on a different port.  Some may block the protocol in general, but you may be able to SSH to the server and tunnel FTP over that (or use SFTP).

Comment: and of course don't exist desktop applications that can emulate a web FTP gateway because you need a dedicated server for this.

Comment: @Bakaburg: I guess I've been working on the assumption so far that you have a server to which you'd like to connect from various other networks.  If it's not your server, and it's not your network, then I'm afraid you have very little control over what you can do to connect.  And any solution in that case would very much be on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: So the only way is to try every protocol and see if you're able to pass through? excuse me for my ignorance i hope it does make sense: I have to change the port of the ftp connection? or my ports?

Comment: @Bakaburg: What exactly are you in control of here?  If you control the server, you can run an FTP service on non-standard ports.  If you don't, then you probably can't.  However, if you at least control a web site on the server then you can set up a web FTP gateway, which remains the most likely solution.

Comment: about two post ago. Yes I have my server, i meant that an imaginary app that allows you to send file to a server without passing through ftp would need a dedicated server that receive the files and send them to your server. To be clear, a web app like net2ftp, should works like this: "client -> (http) -> net2ftp server -> (ftp) -> my server" and vice-versa. Isn't it? so a desktop app should have a dedicated server to achieve this functionalities.

Comment: this is start to looking like a chat : ). The fact is that I have many domains, so i would need a solution that works with whichever server you can access.

Comment: @Bakaburg: An "FTP Gateway" web app doesn't necessarily ever use the actual FTP protocol.  It just lightly mimics the functionality of being able to transfer files to and from the server, but does it all over HTTP.  And running an actual FTP service on a non-standard port isn't as complex as you're implying.  The server software (some kind of FTP daemon) should be configurable to listen on a specific port, and any decent FTP client (which you'd be running on your mac) should be able to specify a port to which to connect.  Note, however, that some places will still block that.

Comment: @Bakaburg: Well, more accurately, an FTP client would use an FTP connection over a non-FTP port.  You wouldn't want an FTP server listening on your HTTP port because it would disable your HTTP server.  Hmm, you're right.  It looks like net2ftp does hook in to an existing FTP server.  Either way, the communication between the web application and the FTP running on the same server is local, so anything goes.  The communication between your mac and net2ftp is over HTTP, so it should work fine pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To turn your request around [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) provides remote file access over a variety of protocols including ftp ([tramp mode),](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TrampMode) and [can function as a web browser as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs/W3). If you really want it to run in a browser you can find a web terminal emulator and run emacs from the command-line.